# API getting timed out after passing from gateway so unable to get result in client side

Tags: node.js, reactjs, frontend

I am working on a reporting module frontend (React JS) and the API to fetch data generally takes 50-55 seconds to send the response, but the request passes through a gateway and gets timed out after 30 seconds.

I don't have control over the gateway and very limited access to server. Cannot implement caching on the API.
I have tried to break the request and response. I create a unique id for each request and send it to frontend and then poll the backend to check if the report is generated.

Can anyone suggest a better optimized way to perform this activity other than polling? Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks a lot.